# How to make a self-sustaining necropolis?

Tags: magic, economy, fauna, flora, cities

My living friends. I'm a Lich, a wizard that became a undead and obtained immortality, I am looking to build a necropolis for me to be its king, I chose a distant city to turn it's inabitants into various types of undead, like zombies, ghost, vampires, skeletons, dullahans and others, but although I am undead king to be, I want my city to be a bit more 'lively' like having its own products, food production, fabrics and stuff, everything for internal consumption, here are some restrictions.

- Vampires drink blood, skeletons need calcium, zombies eat flesh, ghost feeds on emotions.
- Living beings don't adapt well to my city since the place is corrupted, there are a few exceptions, like bats, rats, snakes, worms, lawyers, some types os fish and bugs... You know the dark creatures. Here are few key points.
  -I would need plants that survive harsh enviroments and are useful to the food, textil industry and also decoration since I love flowers.
- The city is a late European medieval village in France, from century XI.
- I have no problems acquiring any material, plant or animal in the world.
- My city is clouded most of the time but I can allow sun-light to arrive at specific places, like the fields at necessary times.

So how can I make a self-sustaining necropolis?

Comment: A lich concerned about city building instead of himself is refreshing!

Comment: This is a cracking question.

Comment: You could probably create a permanent influx of lawyers to your country by making it adopt modern USA healthcare practices.

Comment: And exploit the living like that? I am not that evil.

Comment: What's your attrition rate? How often does an undead citizen become less productive or non productive? This will control the rate at which you need add to your population.

Comment: They are literally not allowed to leave, are magically immortal, cannot reproduce and usually maintain a lethargique productivity when they are not entertained, like you average office worker, are they all not like that? but I struggle to find ways to make their afterlife better, so they can serve me better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it looks like you have everything you need!

### Crops

For starters, there's only one kind of crop I'd recommend for such a task. Grains. Grains such as wheat, rye, and barley are a hardy crop that can survive even in harsh conditions and soil.

### Living Crops

Your grains are going to feed your true crop: Rats and bats. You see, most of the other creatures are going to be too expensive or not give you what you need. The predatory creatures like snakes are too expensive, ecologically. And you'll need mammals to feed those ghosts, and everyone knows lawyers don't have emotions.The rats feed on grain, and the bats on the local insects. All you need to do is provide them shelter! They can be bled, fed, and ground for the vampires zombies and skelebois, and they are quite easily spooked, keeping your ghosts satiated as well.  Of course, we can't forget the cockroaches. They'll eat anything the rats wont, and are an excellent source of protein for your lawyers. Thanks, Joe.

Viola! you have a rat and bat sustained Necropolis! Extra spooky. Keep a few snakes and lawyers around for good measure, of course. Nothing like the threat of venom to keep the murderhobos at bay.

Comment: Don’t forget cockroaches!! They’ll eat anything the rats won’t and they’re a handy source of protein for the lawyers!

Comment: @JoeBloggs By the Bones, you're right. How could I forget. Thanks joe, edited.

Comment: It is a excelent idea, I was having trouble thinking in what to do with all those lawyers, raising them is hard without a university in my city and the lack of crime to generate the enviroment for they growth.

Answer (score 8):

**Suburb.**

Your city of the dead (more a town of the dead) is one suburb of a bustling metropolis.  The large adjacent live city provides the fodder you need for your undead, but also a market for your excellent garments, footwear and specialty liqueurs.

There are downsides to living next to the suburb of the dead, like they occasionally show up.  But Deadsville can be a trippy place to visit for night life; rendezvous with your old buddy Boris (killed running with the bulls) and he will show you around his new haunts.

Bonus: when the country goes to war and the Queen imposes a draft, some of the undead will be drafted too.  Fair is fair.

Comment: What a great idea, although not self-susteined, it provides a good way for my people to integrate society, we will definitelly dominate the funerary industry. Can't pay for your funeral? you pay it  yourself working after dead.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can't plant and grow people to feed upon, then the Lich King needs to attract humans to his Necropolis.

A time-honored way to get people to move to a place is for there to be an economic opportunity that is worth the risk.  Imaginably, the Lich King has little use for wealth beyond its material use as spell components and hiring humans to do something that only humans can do for him, whatever that may be.  If that wealth (gold, silver, gems, artwork, non-magical artifacts) was extractable from the area around the Necropolis, and stories circulated among human populations of easy riches with some risk, then humans will come.

The more the humans perceive the risks as lower than they actually are and their perceptions of wealth are greater than they might actually be, then the larger and more stable the human population will become.

One would imagine it as small groups of prospectors panning for gold and gems.  Those grow into larger operations extracting valuable metals and gems paying good wages to workers to come to the vicinity of the Necropolis.  Then come the merchants and bars and brothels, then banks evens.

Since the extractive industries are dangerous, and people die all the time in mines, and through human treachery when lots of easy money is on that table, the Necropolis would effectively have a free-range human ranch. The key is for the human population to perceive that the extractive industries and other people are the primary danger, and the perceived danger of the Necropolis be smaller.

The Lich King should secretly control the town's newspaper or equivalent for middle ages french village and psychically dominate the priests and deacon preaching in the village churches.

Comment: Yep.  People get really bad at judging risk vs reward as the reward grows.  See also:  Lottery.  As in "the Lottery is a tax on people who are bad at math".